# Mysql with vb6.0 localhost issue

Tags: vb6

Pls pls help me

in my server it's written as Server: Localhost via UNIX socket

my domain name is "datadarshan.com"

and my vb6.0 code is

```
serverip = "datadarshan.com"
port = "3306"
datebasename = "XXXXX"
user = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXXX"


table_name = "adminLoginDB"

'Creating a new connection, and defineing the variables

Set CNN = New Connection
CNN.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" _
& "SERVER=" & serverip & ";" _
& " DATABASE=" & datebasename & ";" _
& " PORT=" & port & ";" _
& "UID=" & user & ";PWD=" & password & "; OPTION=3"

CNN.Open       'Opening the database
```

I m getting error.....
so what i have to write in server ip even i tried "localhost" also but still getting the error for connection.

Thanks in adv,
Chirag Shah.

Comment: What is the error message

Answer (score 0):

Try "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" and see if that works.

Sometimes `localhost` isn't defined on Windows.

By the way: It could also be a firewall issue, of course :).

Comment: thanks for the answer but my question is my domain name is datadarshan  and if i write localhost or "127.0.0.1" but how my vb program knows that i have to connect to which server.

Comment: Pls help me out with the demo code in vb6.0 with Localhost via UNIX socket